# How can I upload a json file (or JavaScript Object) to IPFS in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ipfs, ipfs-http-client, pinata

I am trying to upload the metadata(JavaScript Object) of a file already uploaded to IPFS, from the client side in the NextJS. I am able to upload files(PDFs) to IPFS using the `Infura's HTTP API` with the help of the `ipfs-http-client` package, but I am not able to do so with JSON?
I have also tried uploading using the `pinata SDK` but in vain.
How can I upload the JavaScript object to IPFS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Short Answer:** Perform `JSON.stringify()` on the JavaScript Object and upload the returned value to the IPFS. You can either use Infura's HTTP API end-point or `ipfs-http-client` which is a client library for the IPFS HTTP API.

**The Long Answer:**

#### Uploading a file from user's disk:-

##### 1. Using the `ipfs-core` package:

- install the ipfs-core package

```bash
yarn add ipfs-core
```

- using ipfs-core package

```js
import * as IPFS from 'ipfs-core'      

const ipfs = await IPFS.create()       //creating an IPFS node
//passing the file object  extracted from the HTML input.
const { cid } = await ipfs.add(file)   
console.info(cid) // QmXXY5ZxbtuYj6DnfApLiGstzPN7fvSyigrRee3hDWPCaf
```

##### 2. Using a public IPFS gateway

- You can use [this](https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0) public IPFS gateway provided by Infura and use it to upload the files directly by sending a post request to this IPFS gateway.
- You can refer to [this](https://dev.to/sameer472/how-to-upload-files-on-ipfs-infuraio-using-react-56g) post on [dev.to](https://dev.to).

#### Uploading a JavaScript Object as a JSON:-

- You can upload a JavaScript Object to IPFS in the form of JSON text.
- First, you have to stringify the JSON using `JSON.stringify(<JS_OBJECT>)` and upload the returned value of this function to the IPFS.
- You can use either of the two methods discussed above for uploading the value returned by this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pinata-api](https://docs.pinata.cloud/pinata-api) without third party library

from the client you send the metadata to the server and the server sends post a request to `pinata`.

```
    const url = `https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinJSONToIPFS`;
    const res = await axios.post(
      url,
      {
        pinataMetadata: {
          name: "add a name",
        },
        // assuming client sends `nftMeta` json
        pinataContent: req.body.nftMeta,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          pinata_api_key: yourPinataApiKey,
          pinata_secret_api_key: yourPinataSecretApiKey,
        },
      }
    );
```

Comment: The free pinata plan has limits to the number of IPFS uploads and fetches and stops working after the limit has reached.